# For any function $f ∈ F(M )$, $f X ∈ V(M)$

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, vector-fields

Let $X ∈ V(M)$ be a vector field.
To show: for any function $f ∈ F(M )$, $f X ∈ V(M)$.

I thought:

Given $f ∈ F(M)$ and
$X ∈ V(M)$ we define $(fX)(x) := f(x)X(x)$ for all $x ∈ M$. And $F(M)$ is the set of the differentiable fonction.

Comment: Careful, $fX \neq Xf$. You are making a confusion while saying "$fX$ is the directional derivative".

Comment: @Didier ah yes sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $C^\infty$ case, a vector field $X\in \mathcal{X}(M)$ is an $\mathbb R$-linear map

$$X\colon C^\infty(M)\to C^{\infty}(M)$$

such $X(h\cdot g) = h\cdot X(g) + g\cdot X(h)$ for every $g, h\in C^{\infty}(M)$.

Now, if $f\in C^\infty(M)$ and $X\in \mathcal X(M)$, $fX$ is still $\mathbb R$-linear and obeys
$$(fX)(hg) = f\cdot X(hg) = f \cdot \big( h\cdot X(g) + g\cdot X(h) \big) = h\cdot (fX)(g) + g\cdot (fX)(h)$$

Comment: Is enough to say that it $fX$ a vector field?

Comment: In $C^\infty$ case, yes. See [Theorem 2.1](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derivations+of+smooth+functions+are+vector+fields)